# How to get original Ubuntu surround control

Tags: sound

I use UbuntuStudio 18.04.1 LTS.

Unfortunately, this Ubuntu version doesn't have the original Ubuntu sound control (like this [image]).

Is there some way to download that app individually? How? From where?

Comment: What desktop environment do you use on UbuntuStudio? The UI your mentioned is available in Unity, GNOME sHell and MATE.

Comment: I use GNOME desktop and I don't have that app.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with GNOME sHell this menu is callable with

```
gnome-control-center sound
```

and then by clicking on *Test Speakers* button:

[image: gnome-control-center sound]

Also you can access this menu from top right corner, then selecting *Settings*

[image: Open GNOME Control Center]

and choose *Sound* tab.

Comment: I installed GNOME desktop enviroment on my UbuntuStudio 18.04.1 LTS, but... gnome-control-center, with or without  the sound statement, doesn't work. I guess something is missed here, but I don't have any clue about.